# How do I modify this plotly line graph?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

I am very new to plotly. Unable to find answers on its documentation.
I created this line chart but i am unable to modify the line chart
Example:

1. I want two markers on one line
2. renaming axis and legend

   ```
   data_hum = pd.melt(data,id_vars=['time'],value_vars=['hum_1','hum_2'])
   fig = px.line(data_hum,x='time',y='value',color='variable')
   ```

how to create line chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using plotly.graph_objects instead of plotly.express if you want to have more options how to customize your plots.

In your examples this could look something like this

```
data_hum = pd.melt(data,id_vars=['time'],value_vars=['hum_1','hum_2'])
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data_hum['time'], y=data_hum['hum_1'],
                mode='lines+markers',
                name='Legend label 1'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data_hum['time'], y=data_hum['hum_2'],
                    mode='lines+markers',
                    name='Legend label 2'))
```

Checkout the official documentation for more information:
https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#line-plot-with-goscatter

Comment: Thank you, this works well! I tried it this way, realized there is no need of using pd.melt.

Comment: we can also use fig.update_layout() to name the axis and titles

Comment: @Sca, glad I could help. Could you also accept the answer if it solved your problem? :)

Comment: @Sca You've clearly gotten the assistance you were looking for here. Please consider marking the suggestion from LeBavarois as the accepted solution. Your question history shows that you have not yet accepted any solution for *any* answer. So you may not know how that works? The way you accept answers is by clicking the checkmark right below the answer score. And the people who have kindly provided your answers would likely not mind that you use the upvote button from time to time either.